# iOS not respecting jpeg image 32MP limit - how to fix

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, jpeg, limit

As title states and as searching on google can give, on iOS there is a limit for what the devices can handle for jpeg images. 
As per Apple [docs (Know iOS Resource Limits)](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW1):

> Because of the memory available on iOS, there are limits on the number
>   of resources it can process:
>
> - The maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels
>     for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices
>     with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM. That is, ensure that width *
>     height ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024 for devices with less than 256 MB RAM. Note
>     that the decoded size is far larger than the encoded size of an image.
> - **The maximum decoded image size for JPEG is 32MP megapixels using
>     subsampling**. JPEG images can be up to 32 megapixels due to
>     subsampling, which allows JPEG images to decode to a size that has one
>     sixteenth the number of pixels. JPEG images larger than 2 megapixels
>     are subsampled—that is, decoded to a reduced size. JPEG subsampling
>     allows the user to view images from the latest digital cameras.

I added the enfasis on the point that's bugging me mostly. I'm trying to display a fairly big image, but still largely in the above 32MP mentioned limit, specifically its a **3995px * 2138px** for a total of **8.5MP** and **396kb** weight (jpeg quality/compression set to 25 via PS).

Still whenever I call for that image as ex. source of an `<img>` tag, nothing is displayed on any iOS device I've been able to test, on emulators and couple real devices (iphone4, ipad2, 3, mini...).

Is there anything I'am missing blatantly or maybe I've not understand from the docs above?

What can I do apart replace it with a reduced file size? If forced to replace it, what is the highest width I can reach without breaking? How can I ensure iOS honor the 32MP limit mentioned?

I'm speaking in a website perspective, not a native app on the device.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fix your current problem but if you look at image handling in IOS8 there are no longer any image size limits (CoreImage can automatically tile) - perhaps you could target that?

Comment: As you said it doesn't unfortunately help with my currrent problem, but is indeed a nice info to add. Do you have any source to link for further documentation?

Comment: Watch the WWDC "What's new in Core Image" video, I don't know where in the docs it states that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can split up images and tile them.I routinely display images 180,000 x 120,000 pixels on IOS devices by chopping them up and using a CATiledLayer.